# Creating a new organisation as a deployment administrator fails

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In our current development environment we have the developer accounts configured as deployment managers. We're running CRM as a separate CRM account.

When I create a new organization, using the MS Dynamics CRM Deployment Manager, running under my own account, the validation step gives me the following error:

```
The current user does not have required permissions (read/write)
for the following Active Directory group:
CN=/*rest of AD info*/
```

I don't get any errors when I either *import* an organization rather than *create* one, or run the tool as the *CRM user*.

Why can't CRM deployment managers create new organizations, yet have no problem importing one in our setup?

Comment: It seems as if the Deployment Manager wants to create the first user (System Administrator) with the account that deployment manager is running under, rather than letting the CRM deployment handle it (under the CRM service user).